# Oracle exp dump file import issue IMP-00009: abnormal end of export file

Tags: oracle, imp

While importing an oracle database via imp, it terminates with below error

```
IMP-00009: abnormal end of export file
Import terminated successfully with warnings.
```

The exp was run on the same machine (the data was not ftp between servers)

Is there a way to recover tables from this file?

Comment: Is this the entire error message ?

Comment: yes, thats the only error message followed by termination message

Comment: Maybe then a corrupt file try exp again with compress=y option, i am afraid nothing else in mind as of now  for this

Answer (score 1):

Check your Dump file size. I was getting the same error because my .dmp file was of 0KB

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly be caused by the combination OS and Oracle versions not allowing importing dumps bigger than 2gb

Answer (score 0):

http://www.serkey.com/tag/oracle-imp-00009/
here you will find lots of people discussing same thing.